# Удалить из каждой строки двумерного массива последний элемент

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Количество элементов в каждой строке рандомно. Проблема, как я понял, в выводе 2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void create(int**& ar, int*, int&);
void fill(int**, int, int, int*);
void print(int**, int&, int, int*);
void deleteArray(int**& ar, int& , int);
void deleteLast(int**& ar, int*, int&);

int main() {
    system("color 0F");
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    cout << "Введiть рядочки i стовпчики: \n";
    int m, n;
    int& refm = m;
    int& refn = n;
    cin >> m;
    int*cols = new int[m];
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        *(cols + j) = rand() % 5 + 5;
    }
    cout << *(cols);
    int **ar = 0;
    create(ar, cols, refm);
    fill(ar, m, n, cols);
    cout << endl;
    //deleteArray(ar, refm, n);
    print(ar, refm, n, cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < refm; i++) {
        *(cols + i) -= 1;
    }
    deleteLast(ar, cols, refm);
    cout << endl;
    print(ar, refm, n, cols);  // <== Ошибка здесь, кажется 

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void create(int**& ar, int* cols, int& refm) {
    ar = new int*[refm];
    for (int i = 0; i < refm; i++) {
        *(ar + i) = new int[*(cols + i)];
    }
}

void fill(int** ar, int m, int n, int* cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *(cols + i); j++) {
            *(*(ar + i) + j) = rand() % 5;
        }
    }
}

void print(int** ar, int& refm, int n, int* cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < refm; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *(cols + i); j++) {
            cout  << *(*(ar + i) + j) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void deleteArray(int**& ar, int& refm, int n) {
    int **ar1 = 0;
    ar1 = new int*[0];
    refm = 0;
    delete[]ar;
    ar = ar1;
}

void deleteLast(int**& ar, int* cols, int& refm) {
    int **ar1 = 0;
    ar1 = new int*[refm];
    for (int i = 0; i < refm; i++) {
        *(ar1 + i) = new int[*(cols + i)];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < refm; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *(cols + i); j++) {
            *(*(ar1 + i) + j) = *(*(ar + i) + j);
        }
    }
    delete[]ar1;
    ar = ar1;
}
```

Comment: Что-то у вас ссылки используются там, где они ни к чему. Например, в `print` - зачем передача по ссылке второго параметра? и зачем создавать эту ссылку `refm`, если можно просто передать `m`? При этом рядом, в `fill` все нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этой функции

```
void deleteLast(int**& ar, int* cols, int& refm) {
    int **ar1 = 0;
    ar1 = new int*[refm];
    for (int i = 0; i < refm; i++) {
        *(ar1 + i) = new int[*(cols + i)];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < refm; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *(cols + i); j++) {
            *(*(ar1 + i) + j) = *(*(ar + i) + j);
        }
    }
    delete[]ar1;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^        
    ar = ar1;
}
```

Вы удаляете только что созданный новый массив `ar1`. На самом деле вместо удаления `ar1` вы должны удалить всю память, адрессуемую указателем `ar`.

Объявите и определите функцию `deleteArray` следующим образом

```
void deleteArray( int**& ar, int refm ) 
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < refm; i++ ) delete [] ar[i];

    delete [] ar;

    ar = nullptr;
}
```

И вызовите эту функцию в функции `deleteLast`

```
void deleteLast(int**& ar, int* cols, int& refm) {
    int **ar1 = 0;
    ar1 = new int*[refm];
    for (int i = 0; i < refm; i++) {
        *(ar1 + i) = new int[*(cols + i)];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < refm; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *(cols + i); j++) {
            *(*(ar1 + i) + j) = *(*(ar + i) + j);
        }
    }
    deleteArray( ar, refm );
    ^^^^^^^^^^^        
    ar = ar1;
}
```

Также не забудьте вызывать эту функцию перед выходом из `main`

```
deleteArray( ar, refm );
delete [] cols;
```

Обратите внимание, что параметр `n`, присутствующих во многих определениях ваших функций, не используется. Его можно удалить.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вы используете С++, вы могли бы решить ту же самую проблему при помощи стандартного контейнера `std::vector`, который поддерживает все используемые вами операции. В таком случае вашу задачу можно было бы решить вот так (версия C++11 и выше):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned col_num = 8;
    unsigned row_num = 8;

    // Создать двумерный вектор с изначальным размером row_num * col_num
    vector<vector<int>> vec( row_num, vector<int>(col_num, 0));

    // Заполнить случайными значениями
    for (auto& Row : vec)
        for (auto& Col : Row)
            Col = rand() % 5;

    // Вывести все значения на экран
    for (auto& Row : vec)
        for (auto& Col : Row)
            cout << Col << " ";
    cout << endl;

    // Удалить последнее значение в каждом ряду
    for (auto& Row : vec)
        Row.pop_back();

    // Удалить всё
    vec.clear();
}
```

Это гораздо проще и безопаснее, при этом производительность `std::vector` эквивалентна производительности стандартного массива, а в некоторых случаях может быть выше (если ваше собственное решение менее эффективно).

Comment: Спасибо, но только учусь, к вектору еще не дошел.

Comment: @AdamHodovanets Я вам советую сразу изучить работу с вектором, потому что он и удобнее, и безопаснее в работе чем C-массив, и в реальном коде на С++ (не на С) будет встречаться гораздо чаще. И даже если вам правда нужны будут массивы, проще ими пользоваться, когда вы уже освоили стандартные контейнеры и алгоритмы. [Здесь](http://cppstudio.com/post/8453/) вы найдете небольшое руководство по вектору, а по [этой ссылке](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) - полное описание класса. Обратите внимание на методы `push_back()`, `clear()` и `size()`.